# Spring boot use both SSM and application profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to be able to use both SSM and application profiles, i.e., *application-dev.yml*, *application-qa.yml*, *application-prod.yml*. The problem is, if I set *spring.profiles.active=dev* in the *application.yml*, it will use the correct version - *application-dev.yml* in this example, but it no longer looks at SSM.

Is there a way I can use both and have the hierarchy be:

1. SSM
2. application-dev.yml
3. applicaion.yml

or is it one or the other?

**Some of the specs**

- Spring boot: 2.6.6
- Java: Open JDK 11
- SSM: standard AWS SSM

Comment: What is SSM? How are you using this in the first place?

Comment: @M.Deinum it's this https://source.coveo.com/2018/08/03/spring-boot-and-aws-parameter-store/ Spring Boot comes with native integration and it allows you to put secrets in there vs the properties file

Comment: Shouldn't you be using Spring Cloud Config with AWS instead of rolling your own?